# How to retrieve data from firestore into your MPChart like barchart and piechart in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, bar-chart, pie-chart

// this is my java code for the bar chart and piechart I don't know how to retrieve data from the firestore into my piechart or bar chart

```
public class StatisticFragment extends Fragment {

FirebaseAuth fAuth;
FirebaseFirestore db;
String userID;

LineChart lineChart;
LineData lineData;
LineDataSet lineDataSet;
ArrayList lineEntries;

BarChart weeklyIncomeBarchart;
ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntryArrayList;
ArrayList<String> labelsName;
ArrayList<WeeklyIncomeChart> weeklyIncomeCharts = new ArrayList<>();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_statistic, container, false);

    getActivity().setTitle("Statistic");

    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    lineChart = v.findViewById(R.id.lineChart);
    getEntries();
    lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(lineEntries, "");
    lineData = new LineData(lineDataSet);
    lineChart.setData(lineData);
    lineDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS);
    lineDataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    lineDataSet.setValueTextSize(18f);

    //Weekly Income Barchart
    weeklyIncomeBarchart = v.findViewById(R.id.weeklyIncomeBarchart);

    barEntryArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    labelsName = new ArrayList<>();
    fillWeeklyIncome();
    for(int i = 0; i < weeklyIncomeCharts.size(); i ++){
        String days = weeklyIncomeCharts.get(i).getDays();
        int income = weeklyIncomeCharts.get(i).getIncome();
        barEntryArrayList.add(new BarEntry(i, income));
        labelsName.add(days);
    }

    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntryArrayList, "Days");
    barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
    Description description = new Description();
    description.setText("Weekly Income");
    weeklyIncomeBarchart.setDescription(description);
    BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSet);
    weeklyIncomeBarchart.setData(barData);

    //set XAxis values formater
    XAxis xAxis = weeklyIncomeBarchart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(labelsName));

    //set position of labels(Days name)
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.TOP);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setLabelCount(labelsName.size());
    xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(270);
    weeklyIncomeBarchart.animateY(2000);
    weeklyIncomeBarchart.invalidate();

    return v;
}

private void getEntries() {
    lineEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(2f, 0));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(4f, 1));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(6f, 1));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(8f, 3));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(7f, 4));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(3f, 3));
}

private void fillWeeklyIncome(){
    weeklyIncomeCharts.clear();
    weeklyIncomeCharts.add(new WeeklyIncomeChart("Sunday", 150));
    weeklyIncomeCharts.add(new WeeklyIncomeChart("Monday", 200));
    weeklyIncomeCharts.add(new WeeklyIncomeChart("Tuesday", 250));
    weeklyIncomeCharts.add(new WeeklyIncomeChart("Wednesday", 300));
    weeklyIncomeCharts.add(new WeeklyIncomeChart("Thursday", 350));
    weeklyIncomeCharts.add(new WeeklyIncomeChart("Friday", 400));
    weeklyIncomeCharts.add(new WeeklyIncomeChart("Saturday", 450));
}
```

}

// this is my xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                android:id="@+id/lineChart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp" />

            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
                android:id="@+id/weeklyIncomeBarchart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lineChart"/>


        </RelativeLayout>



</FrameLayout>
```

//this can be run but the only problem is that I want to use the data from firestore as the data for the chart but does not know how to do it

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm a beginner at android studio so I've only able to do the piechart and the barchart but the data retrieving part from the firestore is so hard for me implement on this type of MPChart

Comment: Please add the code that you are using and tell us what exactly doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: sorry I'm new at using stackoverflow I've already posted my code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the data from Firestore you can use the following code as an example:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

you can get more information of how the read operation works [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#java)

Best regards.